# Never receiving multi-byte returns in rust using serialport-rs

Tags: rust, serial-port

I am using serialport-rs to do some run of the mill UART communications. When talking back and forth with the peripheral, as long as the return from the machine is 1 byte, I receive that no problem. If however I send a request that is expecting a multi-byte response, I can sit in a loop reading forever and I never get anything back in rust. This is not the case in python using pyserial, it seems to work just fine with multibyte communications. I have verified the raw uart frames being sent in rust and python are identical, so I am not sure why I see this behavior in rust. Here is the rs code:

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::{io, time::Duration};
use serialport::{SerialPort, StopBits, Parity, TTYPort};

pub struct PhClient { serial_port: TTYPort, port_number: u8, poll_address: u8 }


fn main() {
    let mut rx_payload:Vec<u8>  = vec![0x00];
    let port_name = &serialport::available_ports().expect("No serial port")[0].port_name;
    let mut ph_client = PhClient {
        serial_port: serialport::new(port_name, 115200)
            .stop_bits(StopBits::Two)
            .timeout(Duration::from_secs(2))
            .open_native()
            .expect("Failed to open serial port"),
        port_number: 0x00,
        poll_address: 0x62
    };


    loop {
        match ph_client.serial_port.read(&mut rx_payload) {
            Ok(bytes) => {
                if bytes == 1 {
                    println!("receive payload: {:?}", rx_payload);
                    ph_client.port_number = rx_payload[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::TimedOut => (),
            Err(e) => eprintln!("{:?}", e)
        }
    }

    let mode = toggle_rte(&mut ph_client, false);
    println!("toggle rte: {:?}", mode);

    let current_telem = get_current_telemetry(&mut ph_client);
    println!("current telemetry: {:?}", current_telem);

    let memblk_probe = symbyte(&mut ph_client);
    println!("block preset: {:?}", memblk_probe);
}

fn toggle_rte(ph: &mut PhClient, enable: bool) -> bool {
    ack(ph);
    let mut rx: [u8; 1] = [0x00];
    let mut tx: Vec<u8> = vec![ph.port_number, 0x0E, enable as u8];
    tx.extend_from_slice(&crc16(&tx).to_le_bytes());
    tx.remove(0);

    println!("toggle rte: {:?}", tx);
    ph.serial_port.write(&tx).expect("Error toggling RTE");
    ph.serial_port.read(&mut rx).expect("No response toggling RTE");

    rx[0] == ph.port_number
}

fn get_current_telemetry(ph: &mut PhClient) -> Vec<u8> {
    ack(ph);
    let mut rx: Vec<u8> = Default::default();
    let tx: [u8; 1] = [0x1A];

    println!("get current telemetry: {:?}", tx);
    ph.serial_port.write(&tx).expect("Error writing current telemetry payload");
    ph.serial_port.read(&mut rx).expect("Error reading current telemetry from host");

    rx
}

fn memblk_probe(ph: &mut PhClient) -> bool {
    ack(ph);
    let mut rx: [u8; 1] = [0x00];
    let mut tx: Vec<u8> = vec![ph.port_number, 0x01];
    tx.extend_from_slice(&crc16(&tx).to_le_bytes());
    tx.remove(0);

    println!("probe payload: {:?}", tx);
    ph.serial_port.write(&tx).expect("Error accessing memblk command");
    ph.serial_port.read(&mut rx).expect("Error reading memblk start address");

    rx[0] == ph.port_number
}

#[inline]
fn ack(ph: &mut PhClient) {
    let tx: [u8; 2] = [ph.poll_address, ph.port_number];
    ph.serial_port.set_stop_bits(StopBits::One).expect("Error setting stop bits to one");
    ph.serial_port.set_parity(Parity::Mark).expect("Error setting parity to Mark");

    ph.serial_port.write(&tx).expect("Error ACKing to target device");

    ph.serial_port.set_parity(Parity::Space).expect("Error setting parity to Space");
}

#[inline]
fn crc16(msg: &[u8]) -> u16 {
    let mut crc: u16 = 0;
    let (mut c, mut q): (u16, u16);

    for byte in msg.iter() {
        c = *byte as u16;
        q = (crc ^ c) & 0o17;
        crc = (crc >> 4) ^ (q * 0o10201);
        q = (crc ^ (c >> 4)) & 0o17;
        crc = (crc >> 4) ^ (q * 0o10201);
    }

    crc
}
```

In the initial read, I am able to obtain the correct frame "10000000111" written to the port. After toggle_rte the expected UART frame is "10010101111" and that is what I receive. The call to get_current_telemetry writes an almost identical message to toggle_rte, but always times out on the read, despite reading the correct response in python (8 bytes). The call to memblk_probe then sends a different single byte to the ph client and it successfully reads the one byte response and returns, as well as changing some memory configuration on the target device, so it is clearly a successful communication. Any ideas as to why the one byte requests/responses are working while anything longer than that just times out with 0 bytes read no matter the fact that python is not seeing any issues in reading those bytes in a timely manner?

Comment: "*I am able to obtain the correct frame '10000000111' ... the expected UART frame is '10010101111'*" - You're showing us what you claim are "*UART frames*", but in an unspecified bit order. However those cannot possibly be valid UART frames because the first bit is identical to the last bit. The start bit is the inverse of the stop bit(s).

Comment: While that would certainly be true of a typical UART, the system in question is only prototypical in one of a handful modalities it defines. Early communication negotiations are pretty bog standard. Beyond that, and dependent upon which permutation of components are actively in use at a given time, the modality will most likely change, and the composition of a frame changes as well. I will make sure to pass on your disapproval to the Israeli's however, they are the ones who made the darn system back in the late 70's.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this issue, the rectification was two-fold. `ph.serial_port.flush().expect("Error flushing buffer");`
solved part of the issue and the second was to not attempt to read into a Vector of unspecified length. Once I started passing [u8; usize] to the read as opposed to Vec<u8>, I started getting exactly what I was looking for. The serial port flush was included in the "ack" function between the write and change in parity. Hope this helps!